# Different Map Styles using Javascript

Tags: javascript, maps

I need help.
I want to make a map using javascript but with different map styles.
How can i do that?

I have this code for setting only one map style:

```
var options = {
                zoom: 6,
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.435947810360242, 121.01270109415054),
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            },
            styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        }
      ],
        };
```

So for example, i have the map stykes coce in another javascript and i want to include it to my javascript that wil create the map.
How to include that file and map styles using javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you need styles you can use

```
var styles = options.styles;
```

This way you can get the `styles` object.

Comment: Can you give me a example?because i'm new in javascript